# QuickActionDefaultsHandler not working in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, console, quickaction

I can't seem to get the QuickActionDefaultsHandler to work at all in Lightning.

Is there anybody that has got it working? Specifically, I'm using the Service Console.

Just to be clear: the "Enable Default Email Templates or the Default Handler for Email Action" *is* set and is pointing to the correct class.

Update from 2019: this now works in Lightning! See https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_cases_email_apex_default_fields.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this is not supported in Lightning. 
In my organization, I mainly overcame this by including the desired logic in a unified Custom HTML email template, and set it as a default for the Email action. Also, I added the recipient list, email subject, FROM, to, cc and bcc fields as formulas in predefined fields on that same Email action. 
If you'll share your class here, along with the various email templates, i'll be able to assist.

Comment: Good to know for sure that it's not yet supported in Lightning! I've now also gone with setting Predefined Fields, which does the job for now. Thanks!

Comment: @WillemMulder would you be able to share where/how you set your "Predefined Fields" to set the default `FROM` email address in LEX?

Comment: @SwisherSweet - here's an example: https://www.screencast.com/t/9Cuy19PVKyJA. Hope this helps.

Comment: @iDog - can you tell me how were you able to include a HTML template as a default for the quick action, the HTML template doesn't even show up in the lookup for me.

Comment: I confirm, it works in Lightning - Feb 2020

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I confirm it it works in lightning. However, I found out following issues in my code:

Mostly people just copy and paste code from here or any article:  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_cases_email_apex_default_fields.htm

```
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(0);
        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject(); 

        Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Priority FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];

        // If case severity is “High,” append “managers@acme.com” to the existing (and possibly blank) BCC field
        if (c.Priority != null && c.Priority.equals('High')) { // Priority is 'High'
            emailMessage.BccAddress = 'managers@acme.com';        
        }        
}
```

> But necessarily "defaults.get(0)" may not be the one you are using on
>   layout. So you need to iterate over all quick actions and find out the
>   correct one as I'm doing below. My quick action developer name is
>   "Email_Member".

```
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null;
        // Check if the quick action is the standard Case Feed send email action
        for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {
            if (defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults && 
                defaults.get(j).getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == EmailMessage.sObjectType && 
                defaults.get(j).getActionName().equals('Case.Email_Member') && defaults.get(j).getActionType().equals('SendEmail')) {
                   sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
                   break;
            }
        }
        system.debug(sendEmailDefaults);

        if (sendEmailDefaults != null) {
            Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Contact.Email, Priority FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
            EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();
            emailMessage.BccAddress = null;
            emailMessage.ToAddress = null;//keep null, contact email will come by default
      }     
    }
```