# Predefined Field Value "From Address" not getting set on Email Case Action

Tags: lightning-experience, case, email2case, lightning-quickaction

After learning that the `QuickActionDefaultsHandler` interface doesn't work with Lightning Experience, I tried to implement the suggestion found in the [comments of this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191715/12290), which is to set the Predefined Field Values for the Email Case Action.

I was able to get the `CC Address` and `BCC Address` to reflect my Predefined Field Values for that action, but for some reason, the `From Address` does not match the Predefined Field Value I set on the action.

The `From Address` I predefined is the Email2Case address I have set in settings, and is verified and working. It's one of the choices when the action is rendered, but the default `FROM` address still shows the logged in user email address.

Are there any other steps I need to take to default the `FROM` address in a LEX Email Case Action?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, I needed to select `From` Predefined Field Name instead of `From Address`. After choosing that option, I was able to select one of the existing validated email address I have setup in my org from a picklist:

[image]

I tested this, and now the Email Case Action defaults to the `FROM` address I specified.

Comment: Can we make the FromAddress readonly?